# Double order by, 1 after limit

Tags: php, mysql, sql-order-by

I've got columns like:

```
counter | name | date | data
```

I would like to sort like this

```
SELECT * FROM monitor order by counter DESC LIMIT $howmuch;
```

That gives me last ten($howmuch) records by counter but i want later order again but by name;

I've tried something like

```
order by counter,name
```

or

```
order by name,counter
```

But none of above gave me what i wanted
Basically I want 10 last records sorted by name.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM monitor order by counter DESC LIMIT $howmuch) AS sub ORDER BY name `

Comment: Probably it wouldn't be issue under normal use BUT i've got in my test names:
Name 1 then Name 10 then Name 2 :/ I mean i literally named name1 etc

Comment: Have you tried `ORDER BY counter DESC, name ASC LIMIT 10`? This way you get the last 10, and they are ordered alphabetically.